# Save as a new entry doesn't seem to copy all locales

Tags: localization

I have a website with 2 locales set up, and have an entry that has content in both.

When I `Save as a new entry`, Craft only saves the locale that is open at the time, and then copies that same content to the other locale, instead of copying the original localised content.

So I end up having one entry with the same content on both locales, instead of having an exact copy of the previous entry (with different content in the 2 locales)

Is this a bug, a normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you see this effect on every fieldtype? Or maybe just on the Matrix?

Comment: Happens to all of them, there are Matrix and Plain Text fields for example, and the behaviour is the same for all, everything is copied correctly, but just for one locale. Then the other locale is copied from the one where the action was made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Craft 2 issue that has been [fixed](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1523) in the upcoming Craft 3 release.

It likely won't be back-ported to Craft 2 since it takes advantage of much larger refactorings.